# Native Android code executes even if I don't package libc++_shared.so

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, libc++, android-native-library

I have pre-built, third-party shared library `libSNPE.so` from Qualcomm that has a dependency on `libc++_shared.so` . Even if I don't copy the `libc++_shared.so` to the Android phone, my programs execute fine.

Trying the above I was expecting that I will get an error that program cannot link to `libc++_shared.so` as it is mentioned that `libc++_shared.so` should be packaged with code https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support. Does this mean that the `libSNPE.so` is linking to the system `libc++.so` at  `/system/lib64/libc++.so` at runtime? Is there a way to verify this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did `ldd` on the executable inside `adb shell`. The executable is linked to */vendor/lib64/libc++_shared.so*.